# Select Query: Error Code 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm attempting to retrieve all the data from a column in mysql by having the user input which table and column the data is through the mysqlconnector library in python. When I ran the query through python no data would show up and then when I ran it through Phpmyadmin I would get these errors:

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Matisse'
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Picasso'
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'van Gogh'
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Deli'
```

I found the query only works for columns that are integer based and does not work for date-time or `varchar` columns (The `L_Name` one from which the query doesn't work is `varchar(25)`.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE L_Name
```

After the query is run and throws those errors, the query changes to this by itself:

```
SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE 1
```

This new query returns the whole table and all of its columns and rows but of course all I want is for it to simply return the single column.

EDIT: To clarify, the point of running the `` SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE L_Name ``
query is to bring up the whole list of values in that column for that table. This is just one case and there's many other cases like if the user wanted to search up a specific record from the art_show table and then look at all the values in the column of the gallery location.

Comment: try SELECT * FROM artist WHERE L_Name = 'Mantisse'

Comment: The problem is, is that I want it to show all of the values in the column without them already knowing there is a Matisse. When they enter the Table and the Column name itll show matisse and the other artist names and once they enter that artist name again into the application, it lists the full row for that artist.

Comment: to get the hole list SELECT * FROM artist is enogh . But i don't understand why they need to enter a table name for. Also there are thousands of Names. Last a simpe artistname = input("Enter teh artist name: ") there you have your value for string comaparison.

Comment: I have a method for getting the whole list already. I just want to because the user doesn't know the values for the tables, columns, and full records. This way they can input it one by one since I have a method that prints the list of tables, then the list of the columns, and then the list of values in that column so they can narrow it down completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its the error thats the problem since you did varchar, maybe check your python code?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. My Python had an issue where it would only print the first value due to how I set up the print statement. Fixed it by changing the query on the 3rd line and also changing the print statement from print(rec[0]) to print(rec)

```
def show_entries(table, column):
    print(f"Here's the records in the table {table} and the column {column}.")
    mycursor.execute(f"SELECT {column} FROM {table}")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for rec in myresult:
        print(rec)
```